# Window 2003 is PHP Limiting my Download Speed?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, php

I have window 2003 100mbps server, i have tried using php script such as php indexer, zina pancake.org and others.

The php script use to serve download such as images and music songs. I personally have 20mbps internet speed. When i use the php script (download pass thru PHP headers) , it will download at constant speed of 30-40KBps.

I have tried different webserver such as apache 1.3, apache 2.2, abyss webserver & lighttpd for windows. The speed while relying on php is same constant 30-40KBps however when i tried direct link/straight from apache, the speed is 1MB/s.

Is there any settings in Window 2003 Registry or PHP should i change to make the download speed is more faster when going thru PHP?

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting 1 MB/s on a local LAN transfer but the PHP transfer is through the local network as well, or being routed over the Internet?

Comment: is that 100mbps bothways? or is this just your downstream? how much has your provider allocated you for upstream?

Comment: its 100mbit up/down, its on internet, not over LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 100 megabit up/down stream connection and you're downloading at 1Mbps? I don't know of any native PHP that would throttle your bandwidth. Chances are this is your ISP QoS level or you may have an issue with throttling/QoS on one of your perimeter routers.

Comment: no, what i meant was, when i download direct link from apache ( directory listing, native, without using php) i can get 1mb/s. However when i try on PHP, the speed become 30kbps.

Comment: @JohnScout PHP isn't a file sharing protocol